# MT4, Retrieve account information NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mt4

I'm looking to build a web application that interfaces with MT4.
How would I, using nodeJS or some other web language, retrieve account information from Metatrader4. Information such as previous orders, account balance ect.

Is this possible?
I'm failing to find information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! but..

You would need an intermediary piece of software to connect to MT4 over its proprietary c++ interface to establish communication between the mt4 and your node.js app

Comment: Would you able to elaborate on this a bit more?
Am really struggling to find any clear guidance on what needs to be done to achieve this.

A platform like myfxbook is a clear example. You link your account with acc no. and investor password, then behind the scenes all your account info and trades and retrieved, with the added benefit of auto updating periodically.

Comment: ye, your not gonna find any of that on MT4. The only way to connect to mt4 is thru a mtmanager interface. A mtmanager.dll that loads in a super archaic way, in c++, and connects you to the mt4 server, at which point depending on your account's permissions you can fetch account, trades, etc...
People, including yours truly, have written various commercial and otherwise open-source SDKs to do this and convert the communication layer to rest or whateverhaveyou. Try to google for mtmanager wrapper or mtmanger sdk/service